# Add a IF CASE or something similar inside a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I have a query result, but there is a field that contains the "PROJECT NUMBER", that appears twice, and where there's supposed to be a COUNT of all the samples, the count appears twice. Any idea how can I solve this?

- Update:

I can now show the table data structure

Here's more or less the info of the tables:

- SAMPLE table

```
+---------------+--------------+--------+--------------+--------------+
| sample_number |    project   | status |    template  | parent_aliquot|
+---------------+--------------+--------------+----------+-------------+
|       1       | S/180318/01  |    C   |  KPS_DEFAULT |      50       |        
|       2       | S/180320/01  |    I   |  KPS_DEFAULT |     100       |
+---------------+--------------+--------+--------------+---------------+
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8Hql.png)

- `KPS_SMP_DUE_DATE_WEEK_PIVOT_VW` table (this table shows the amount of samples of a project that have expired in a year)

```
+---------------+--------------+----------+-------------+----+----+-----+-----+
|    project    |    product   |    year  |  department | w0 | w1 | ... | w53 |
+---------------+--------------+----------+-------------+----+----+-----+-----+
|  S/000260/02  |   Product v1 |    2020  |     MICRO   |  1 |    |     |  1  |  
|  S/180146/04  |   Product v2 |    2021  |      QC     |    |  2 |     |  3  |
+---------------+--------------+----------+-------------+----+----+-----+-----+
```

[image: 2]

Here's the code that I have at the moment:

```
Select
  temp.PROJECT,
  temp.CUSTOMER_DESC,
  temp.PRODUCT,
  ISNULL(temp.PREVIOUS_SAMPLES,0),
  ISNULL(temp.W3,0) as 'W3',
  ISNULL(temp.W4,0) as 'W4',
  ISNULL(temp.W5,0) as 'W5',
  ISNULL(temp.W6,0) as 'W6',
  sum(
    ISNULL(temp.PREVIOUS_SAMPLES,0)
    + ISNULL(temp.W3,0)
    + ISNULL(temp.W4,0)
    + ISNULL(temp.W5,0)
    + ISNULL(temp.W6,0)
  ) as 'TOTAL' 
from (
  SELECT
    vw.PROJECT,
    vw.CUSTOMER_DESC,
    vw.PRODUCT,
    (
      SELECT COUNT(s.SAMPLE_NUMBER)
      FROM SAMPLE s 
      WHERE s.PROJECT = vw.PROJECT
        AND s.STATUS IN ('I', 'U', 'P')
        and s.TEMPLATE = 'KPS_DEFAULT'
        AND s.PARENT_ALIQUOT > 0
    ) as 'PREVIOUS_SAMPLES',
    ISNULL(vw.W3,0) as 'W3',
    ISNULL(vw.W4,0) as 'W4',
    ISNULL(vw.W5,0) as 'W5',
    ISNULL(vw.W6,0) as 'W6' 
  FROM KPS_SMP_DUE_DATE_WEEK_PIVOT_VW vw 
  WHERE vw.DEPARTMENT IN ('QC')
  GROUP BY
    vw.PROJECT,
    vw.CUSTOMER_DESC,
    vw.PRODUCT,
    vw.W3,
    vw.W4,
    vw.W5,
    vw.W6
) as TEMP 
group by
  temp.PROJECT,
  temp.CUSTOMER_DESC,
  temp.PRODUCT,
  temp.PREVIOUS_SAMPLES,
  temp.W3,
  temp.W4,
  temp.W5,
  temp.W6

UNION

Select
  'Total',
  '-',
  '-',
  sum(ISNULL(temp.PREVIOUS_SAMPLES,0) ),
  sum( ISNULL(temp.W3,0)  ),
  sum( ISNULL(temp.W4,0)  ),
  sum( ISNULL(temp.W5,0)  ),
  sum( ISNULL(temp.W6,0) ),
  sum(
    ISNULL(temp.PREVIOUS_SAMPLES,0)
    + ISNULL(temp.W3,0)
    + ISNULL(temp.W4,0)
    + ISNULL(temp.W5,0)
    + ISNULL(temp.W6,0)
  ) 
from (
  SELECT
    vw.PROJECT,
    vw.CUSTOMER_DESC,
    vw.PRODUCT,
    (
      SELECT COUNT(s.SAMPLE_NUMBER) 
      FROM SAMPLE s 
      WHERE s.PROJECT = vw.PROJECT
        AND s.STATUS IN ('I', 'U', 'P')
        and s.TEMPLATE = 'KPS_DEFAULT'
        AND s.PARENT_ALIQUOT > 0
    ) as 'PREVIOUS_SAMPLES',
    ISNULL(vw.W3,0) as 'W3',
    ISNULL(vw.W4,0) as 'W4',
    ISNULL(vw.W5,0) as 'W5',
    ISNULL(vw.W6,0) as 'W6' 
  FROM KPS_SMP_DUE_DATE_WEEK_PIVOT_VW vw
  WHERE vw.DEPARTMENT IN ('QC')
  GROUP BY
    vw.PROJECT,
    vw.CUSTOMER_DESC,
    vw.PRODUCT,
    vw.W3,
    vw.W4,
    vw.W5,
    vw.W6
) as TEMP
```

As seen on the image, I marked the repeated project.

[image: 3]

Comment: Please, remove the tag of IDE (TOAD) and add  the tag of your DBMS ([Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info))

Comment: This does not look like Oracle SQL.

Comment: Most people here want sample table _and expected result_ as formatted text, not images. Don't forget to simplify - [mcve].

Comment: I'd guess, first UNION ALL, then GROUP BY its result.

Comment: 1) You `group by` by W1, W2 etc, but use `isnull(Wn, 0)`, so this will return duplicate rows. 2) You can include the subquery in `with` clause and reuse the code without need to copy-paste it (which is very buggy way). Also there's `rollup` addition to `group by` which calculates totals for you. 3) You should avoid `UNION` where you really do not need to remove duplicates (which is rare case for such totals calculation), use `UNION ALL`. And finally: avoid images of code or data, they are not reusable and not accessible to all. Type in your data as text in question to provide query context

Comment: Hmm in which way does the ISNULL(wn,0) give duplicated rows? I know the ISNULL transforms null characters into 0. It shows the project twice because the product is different, but the total amount of samples is the same.

Comment: @dontknowcoding Because `ISNULL(Wn, 0)` will turn `null` to `0`, so `null -> 0, 0 -> 0`, which will not be grouped.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is way to complicated for anyone else to really figure out.  I would suggest that you simplify it -- and in the process you will probably find the issue.

I can say that your question *claims* that you want one row per project.  However, that is not what the code does.

Your `GROUP BY` is:

```
group by
  temp.PROJECT,
  temp.CUSTOMER_DESC,
  temp.PRODUCT,
  temp.PREVIOUS_SAMPLES,
  temp.W3,
  temp.W4,
  temp.W5,
  temp.W6
```

This says that you want one row for each unique combination of those values.  If you want one row per project, I assume you would simply have:

```
group by temp.PROJECT
```

Of course, the rest of the code would need to be adjusted to handle this.